# Compass sensor goes from 359 to 1, how do I calculate this change as "1 up", rather than "358 down"?

Tags: python, math, sensors, integer-overflow

I have a project with a compass sensor, that outputs the heading in degrees once every second. The change in value is displayed to the user.

So when the sensor rotates from e.g. 283 degress to 285 degress, the program displays "2 up", and when it rotates from 163 degrees to 152 degrees, the program displays "11 down".

My problem is rotating past 359 degrees. When the compas goes from e.g. 358 degrees to 1 degrees the program displays "357 down", but I would like it to say "3 up". I don't know how to achieve this.

It is also a problem going the other way, that is from e.g 5 to 359, "354 up" is returned, instead of "6 down".

Here is my code:

```
# Input from compas sensor:
oldhdg = 358
newhdg = 1

# Calculating and displaying the value change:
if oldhdg == newhdg:
    change = 0
    flowdir = 'stay'
elif oldhdg > newhdg:
    change = oldhdg-newhdg
    flowdir = 'down'
elif newhdg > oldhdg:
    change = newhdg-oldhdg
    flowdir = 'up'
print(f'{change} {flowdir}')
```

output:

```
357 down
>>>
```

Comment: How do you propose to distinguish between a (slow) turn from 358 to 2 via 0, and a (rapid) turn from 358 to 2 via 180 ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark with a slow enough period it's probably irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it holistically. All deltas have two values: "up" and "down". You want to return the lesser of those two values in all cases. Write a function that does that.

```py
def change_in_heading(old, new):
    """Returns the change in heading between two data points

    >>> change_in_heading(100, 99):
    -1
    >>> change_in_heading(99, 100):
    1
    >>> change_in_heading(358, 2):
    4
    >>> change_in_heading(2, 358):
    -4
    """

    delta = new-old
    smallest_change = (delta + 180) % 360 - 180  # clamp to [-180, 180)

    return smallest_change
```

Then you can format to match your existing values with another function:

```py
def display_heading_change(change):
    return f"{abs(change)} {'up' if change >= 0 else 'down'}"
```